# Trying to hold Cart ID and product quantity through JQuery but its returning unidentified value

Tags: jquery, django

This is my HTML and JQuery can anyone tell me where did I go wrong. JQuery is returning unidentified value.

'''

```
    <div class="col-sm-2 product_data1 border-left">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" class="product_id1" value={{ item.id }}>
        <select class="changeStatus" value={{ item.product_quantity }} name="quantity">
        <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
```

'''

And this is my JQuery

```
        $(function () {

            var cart_id = $(this).closest('.product_data1').find('.product_id1').val();
            var product_quantity = $(this).closest('.product_data1').find('.changeStatus').val();
            var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();


            $("select").change(function () {
                alert(cart_id);
                alert(product_quantity);
                alert(token);
            });
        });
```

Comment: without seeing what object `$(this)` refers to we can't tell. So you need to update your html and jquery so we can see that `$(this)` refers to in those

Answer (score 0):

If you just move it inside the select function it will work fine

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var cart_id = $(this).closest('.product_data1').find('.product_id1').val();
    var product_quantity = $(this).closest('.product_data1').find('.changeStatus').val();
    //var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    console.log(cart_id);
    console.log(product_quantity);
    //alert(token);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2 product_data1 border-left">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" class="product_id1" value="{{ item.id }}">
        <select class="changeStatus" value={{ item.product_quantity }} 
        name="quantity">
        <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
```

Hope this helps